# "spark not found" error in scala package command

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am building package for my scala program.

I have imported packages, checked library dependency and revisions in build.sbt but still getting the error for "spark not found". Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I am missing something.

configurations being used are:
scala 2.11.8
hadoop 3.0.0

```
sam@testlab:~/mymooc-workspace/MyProject$ cat src/main/scala/MyProgram.scala 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object MyProgram {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("scala spark")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   val df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("inferSchema","true")
  .option("mode","failfast")
  .load("/home/sam/SparkScala/aadhar_dataset.csv")

  df.show(10,false) 
  }
}
sam@testlab:~/mymooc-workspace/MyProject$ 



sam@testlab:~/mymooc-workspace/MyProject$ sbt package -v
[process_args] java_version = '8'
# Executing command line:
java
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-jar
/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar
package

[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/sam/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/sam/mymooc-workspace/MyProject/project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to project (in build file:/home/sam/mymooc-workspace/MyProject/)
[info] Updating ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn]  * commons-net:commons-net:2.2 is selected over 3.1
[warn]      +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.1.0             (depends on 2.2)
[warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.2.0              (depends on 3.1)
[warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1 is selected over 11.0.2
[warn]      +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:2.4.0           (depends on 14.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:2.4.0            (depends on 14.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:2.4.0         (depends on 14.0.1)
[warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:2.2.0                (depends on 11.0.2)
[warn]      +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.2.0              (depends on 11.0.2)
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/sam/mymooc-workspace/MyProject/target/scala-2.11/classes ...
[error] /home/sam/mymooc-workspace/MyProject/src/main/scala/MyProgram.scala:11:13: not found: value spark
[error]    val df = spark.read
[error]             ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 151 s, completed Dec 5, 2018 10:23:26 AM
sam@testlab:~/mymooc-workspace/MyProject$ 

sam@testlab:~/mymooc-workspace/MyProject$ cat build.sbt 
name := "project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
)


sam@testlab:~/mymooc-workspace/MyProject$
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any value declared in the name of `val spark=?` but you are using that in your program.

From your code snippet what I can understand is your are trying to read a CSV file using `SparkSession` but you haven't declared/created a SparkSession itself. Try the below before reading a file,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
```